# React jest testing useEffect with event Listener

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, use-effect

I want to write a test case to cover the test useEffect, Which is depends on Appcontect value. Can someone please help on this please. Thanks.

```
export const ShareEmail = () => {
  const {
    nextData,
  } = useAppContext();

    const [topic, setTopic] = useState([]);
    
      const generateTopics = () => {
        const topics= nextData.filter(
          (topic: { flag: boolean }) => !topic.flag
        );
        setTopic(topics)
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        generateTopics();
      }, [nextData]);
    
      const generateEmail =() => {
        const emailcontent = topics[0]
      }
    
    return (
          < a
            download="meeting.eml"
            onClick={generateEmail}
          >
            send
          </a>
      );
    }
```

Comment: What did you try? What result did you get?

Comment: Dont understand the question at all.